# WebLogic stuck on internal logging

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic

After executing performance testing, several nodes in Web Logic cluster were stuck with same reason:

```
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '201' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" waiting for lock java.util.WeakHashMap@8632059 BLOCKED

            weblogic.logging.WLLogger.normalizeLogRecord(WLLogger.java:60)

            weblogic.logging.WLLogger.log(WLLogger.java:37)

            weblogic.diagnostics.debug.DebugLogger.log(DebugLogger.java:231)

            weblogic.diagnostics.debug.DebugLogger.debug(DebugLogger.java:204)

            weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperImpl.trace(JDBCWrapperImpl.java:169)

            weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet.preInvocationHandler(ResultSet.java:83)

            weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl.getLong(Unknown Source)
```

There is total 126 threads blocked on the same

```
waiting for lock java.util.WeakHashMap@8632059
```

I really wonder, what could cause this strange behaviour, I was expecting troubles in database performance or lack of jdbc connections, but not logging issues. If so, is it possible to disable this logging somehow?

Other node also had

```
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '206' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" waiting for lock weblogic.logging.FileStreamHandler@153405fb BLOCKED

            com.bea.logging.RotatingFileStreamHandler.publish(RotatingFileStreamHandler.java:75)

            java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:610)

            com.bea.logging.BaseLogger.log(BaseLogger.java:51)

            weblogic.logging.WLLogger.log(WLLogger.java:42)
```

with 15 blocked threads.
The underlying method in all cases does small jpa query, selecting user by login from db due to invalidated cache.

Comment: What version of WebLogic is this? If you leave it for a while do these threads become unblocked?

Comment: WebLogic 12.1.2. I can't leave threads, since jdbc connections blocked inside stuck methods prevent serving other requests in performance test (ofc it leads to test fail)

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, my question was just for diagnosing what's going on. I think your problem is that you have JDBC tracing turned on and it's bottlenecking on a couple of normally innocuous `synchronised` blocks. If you turn the tracing off it should never hit those blocks in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've hit exactly the same problem. Few thread dumps indicated that Weblogic is stuck in some kind of internal debug logging:

```
 - weblogic.diagnostics.debug.DebugLogger.log(java.util.logging.Level, java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable) @bci=56, line=246 (Compiled frame)
 - weblogic.diagnostics.debug.DebugLogger.debug(java.lang.String) @bci=6, line=211 (Compiled frame)
```

Internal debug levels can be configured in Admin Console in Environment > Servers > MyServer > Debug. In my case I discovered that all possible scopes were enabled. After disabling debug logging and restarting server problems disappeared.